# Failed accessing fields of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to process an object passed to the webpage in JSON and had trouble even accessing the fields in it. 
The object is in the format of

```
{  
   "tag":{  
      "edges":{  
         "start1":"end1",
         "start2":"end2"
      },
      "nodes":[  
         "node1",
         "node2"
      ]
   }
}
```

And here is my function:

```
function processSimilarMap(obj){
    for(var o in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(o)){
            var k=obj[o];
            var nodes=k.nodes;//cannot find the field here
            console.log(nodes);
            var edges=k.edges;//cannot find the field here
            console.log(edges);
            for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
                    //do something
            }
            for(var e in edges){
                if(edges.hasOwnProperty(e)){
                    //do something
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However when I passed the object into the function I couldn't reach the field `k.nodes` and `k.edges`. Log shows me they are simply `undefined`. I tried using `k["nodes"]` but it didn't help either. What am I doing wrong here?

Sorry to ask such a low-level question but I'm quite messed up by the fact that objects and maps are in identical format(correct me if I'm wrong). Is there a simpler and more elegant way just like "object.attribute" to handle objects rather than looping all possible attributes(fields) and find those "own properties"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works well for me, how are you calling the function?

Comment: Finally I found one cursed typo which made the json mal-formatted ("&quot;" instead of double quote in the json string). I converted it when parsing and everything works correctly since then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/d01Lxcgm/

```
var obj = {
    "tag": {
        "edges": {
            "start1": "end1",
            "start2": "end2"
        },
        "nodes": ["node1", "node2"]
    }
};
```

Are you sure you are parsing it if its just a JSON string or (and I apologize for asking such a dumb question but just checking the easiest options first) are you sure you called the function and passed the correct object? As far as a more elegant way. If this object is dynamic looping over properties is the best way to do it to make sure you always process everything. If you know the structure of the object will always be the same then you can just access it with dot notation.

```
    var tag = obj.tag;
    var nodes = tag.nodes;
    var edges = tag.edges;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        // do something with nodes
    }
    for (var e in edges) {
        if (edges.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            // do something with edges
        }
    }
```

And of course you can always do array like access as you said in your question:

```
obj['tag'];
```

Comment: I have to say with mixed feelings, that you are correct XD. Really appreciate you reply. I wasn't sure my function works correctly before that.

Comment: @OrlandoL No problem! Happy to help. Out of curiosity why the mixed feelings?

Comment: I'm happy to see problem solved but you know, when you find that the bug is so stupid....

Comment: @OrlandoL oh ok. Sorry I understand what you mean. I misunderstood at first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working, maybe you are not parsing the Json string to an object?

```
var myJson = '{"tag":{"edges":{"start1":"end1","start2":"end2"},"nodes":["node1","node2"]}}';
processSimilarMap(JSON.parse(myJson));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ndtv4dmf/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply! Good to know it actually works as expected but the error resides in my json format.